# How to grep for a pattern in every file involving brackets ${<any-word}

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find

**Environment:** bash (cygwin)

I have a need to grep every file in a directory with a specific extension, and have printed to screen, just the pattern I am looking for.

It must support multiple patterns per line for the file.

The pattern is: dollar sign, left curly, then any word or no word, then right curly bracket, like so:

`$P{<anyword>}`

Preferably a single: `grep` command, or `find`

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep <something> {} \;`

---

The issue is that I have a statement to do this, but it returns the whole line where the expression is found, and I only want the pattern found to be displayed.

---

I am in need of help with finding the regex expression to find the pattern:

`$P{any-series-of-characters-or-numbers-or-dashes-or-underlines-anything-at-all-up-until-the-next-closing-curly-bracket}`

I have tried several things that do not work, and then to print just what is found, but not the file name that it is found in.

Answer (score 1):

given `myFile.txt`:

```
asd
asd
asdf
fdg  dsfg dsf g
askldf ${foo}
${bar} dfsdfg ${}
asdf  asdf
asdfl asdf  ${zzzzz
AKSDHA ASDF {aaaa}
```

`grep -o -E '[$]{[^}]*}' myFile.txt` results in:

```
${foo}
${bar}
${}
```

The regex can definitely be tighten up to cover more use cases....

Comment: This is perfect: grep -o -E '[$P]{[^}]*}' *.txt - but for some reason however, the output will list:  <file_name>:<results> on every line, is there a way that it will just print the values and not the file name?  It may be my version of grep (on cygwin) - grep --version ( grep (GNU grep) 3.0

Comment: adding: --no-filename worked!  Also not important, but it did not print out the leading '$' for me, even if \ escaped, so not sure how I could get that to print?

Comment: I don't know why you're not getting the $. I'm testing under Cygwin and works stated with the posted data sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `grep` flag `-o` (`--only-matching`): "print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching  line".

**UPD:**
`grep --only-matching --no-filename -P '(?<=\$\{)[^}]*(?=\})'`
And if you need to include `${` and `}` to the result, please use
`grep --only-matching --no-filename -E '\$\{[^}]*\}'`

Comment: Is there any help to be offered on the expression that would be used to find all patterns matching:  $P{any-series-of-chars-or-numbers-or-dashes-or-underlines}, have tried several things, and nothing works.

Comment: Also 'grep -o' prints out the:  file_name:<pattern> , but I need just the <pattern> printed to the screen without the preceding file name.

Comment: Try to use: `grep --only-matching --no-filename -P "(?<=\$\{)[^}]+(?=\})"`.
The flag '--no-filename' will prefent from printing file name. If you want, I can explain the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl regular expression :

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep -Po '\$\{[\w-]*\}' {} \;
```